# python REGEX - How Do I remove Square brackets from string?

Tags: python, string

A = """
This is my [name Duty subjected to solve  - time situation ] and finally I called "the man \fjd " so you take of care of that thing.
"""

This is an random string probably similar to my problem.

I wanted to output like this

[name Duty subjected to solve  - time situation  ### Without square brackets but using **finditer** in python aslo I need solution for

the man \fjd                 ### material inside bracket using re.finditer....

```
    a= """This is my [name Duty subjected to solve  - time situation ] and finally I called "the man \fjd " so you take of care of that thing."""
pattern ='''         I nEDD THIS ANSwers                                  '''
    for item in finditer(pattern ,a, re,VERBOSE :
       return(item.groupdict())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need regex just to remove the square brackets?
You can simply use replace to get the job done!

```
a = a.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''])
```

Comment: If it's assignment, you should show some effort to solve it yourself, instead of asking directly in stackoverflow.. Anyways, one regular expression for that case will be pattern = r'\[[\w*\s*\-*]*\]'

Comment: It did in 4 differnet way but when I try to use with re.verbose  retruns  me none type